# Computed columns in SQLCLR project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, sqlclr, calculated-columns

It appears that MS has a bug when dealing with VS 2010 SQL CLR project and computed columns. I am using Pre/PostDeployScript.sql to drop/add the computed column. However, if I try to deploy from VS2010 it, I get dependency errors. The same project works 100% in Vs2008.
I am wondering what my options are in terms of deploying to work around the problem? I am also in contact with MS, but they haven't found a workaround/solution as of yet.

Comment: If you could provide just a bit more info so I can try to reproduce the problem, like what sort of project are you working on and what does it do? Also, what are your pre/post deployment scripts doing?

Comment: Has this now been resolved?  If so please share

Answer (score 1):

You need to install .Net 3.5 and select it inside the project. It will work.